# Does permit and except with the same key make sense in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-parameters

I came across the following in some Rails legacy code:

`params.permit(:a_key).except(:a_key)`

It seems to me that this would produce a null hash every time.  Am I missing something?  I'm very much a non-expert in Rails, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try it `ActionController::Parameters.new(a_key: "foo").permit(:a_key).except(:a_key)`. As to what the original author was trying to do that's more of a mystery.